# How can I insert new values into two related tables?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc

I have a store program in java and a database made in access. I already have 2 tables in my database which are the customers table and the products table.

I want to add an orders table wherein it's primary key is an autonumber and an order_line table to complete this app. I want to have tables like this..

```
customer(cust_id, name, ....)
orders(order_no, cust_id, date_purchased,...)
order_line(order_no, product_id, ...)
products(product_id, product_name, price,....)
```

When the customer purchased the products, i could insert new values to the orders table. The thing that is not clear to me is how could i insert also in the order_line table, because the order_no I created in access is of type autonumber.

Would I make a select statement first to get the order_no value to put it to the order_no in order_line's table? Or I need to put this in one query only.

Anyone with experience to this? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Get the order autonumber from the order table with @@identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insertion into orders and order_line table should happen in a single transaction. While doing so, if you are using plain JDBC to insert record into orders table, you can [register the order_no as an OUT parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter%28int,%20int%29) in your [`CallableStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) and get the value after the statement is executed and use to set the `order_no` attribute on the `order_line` records.

```
 // begin transaction
 connection.setAutoCommit(false);

 CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(INSERT_STMT_INTO_ORDERS_TABLE);
 cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INT);
 int updateCount = cs.execute();
 // Check the update count.
 long orderNo = cs.getInt(1);

 // CallableStatement csLine for inserting into order_line table
 // for (OrderLine line: orderLines) {
 //     Set the orderNo in line.
 //     set paramters on csLine.
 //     csLine.addBatch();
 // }
 // run the batch and verify update counts
 connection.commit();

 // connection.rollback() on error.
```

Comment: I realized that i still don't know a lot of things in jdbc, thanks for this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The JDBC-way (if you like database-independence), is to use the `getGeneratedKeys()` method of statement.

Use `setAutoCommit(false)`, then execute the first query with the option `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` (eg for [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)).

Then use the `getGeneratedKeys()` method to retrieve the key (note: reference by column name, as the exact implementation and number of returned columns depends on the driver implementation.

And execute the second statement with that retrieved key.

Finally, `commit()`.